# Variable con el resultado de una API en PHP

Tags: php, api, stripe

necesito ayuda con un tema de PHP y la API de Stripe.

```
        $stripe->accountLinks->create([
            'account' => 'acct_1HtKYcRm0s9vfiNs',
            'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
            'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
            'type' => 'account_onboarding',
        ]);
```

Eso me devuelve una respuesta así:

```
{
  "object": "account_link",
  "created": 1606772720,
  "expires_at": 1606773020,
  "url": "https://connect.stripe.com/setup/s/QaVzgu7GNGFP"
}
```

Necesito ayuda para saber como mostrar el "url" en una variable en PHP.

He intentado hacer esto pero no funciona:

```
        $link = $stripe->accountLinks->create([
            'account' => 'acct_1HtKYcRm0s9vfiNs',
            'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
            'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
            'type' => 'account_onboarding',
        ]);
        $data = json_decode($link);
        $links = $data->url;
```

Si alguien sabe que puedo hacer me ayudaría mucho. Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Bastaría con:

```
$link = $stripe->accountLinks->create([
    'account' => 'acct_1HtKYcRm0s9vfiNs',
    'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
    'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
    'type' => 'account_onboarding',
]);

$url = $link->url;
```

O en PHP Slim:

```
$account_link = \Stripe\AccountLink::create([
    'account' => 'acct_1HtKYcRm0s9vfiNs',
    'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
    'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
    'type' => 'account_onboarding',
]);
return $account_link->url;
```

Puedes ver un sample completo acá: https://github.com/stripe-samples/connect-onboarding-for-standard/blob/master/server/php/index.php

Comment: ¿Y sabes si hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin PHP Slim?

Comment: Estoy programando sin ningún framework, PHP puro

Comment: Hola @SergioConejo si observas con cuidado en la respuesta que te ofrecen cambian el llamado a create a **llamado a un método estático de la clase** en tu código haces el llamado a un método de una instancia creada. Usa el llamado estático que te proponen (revisando la ubicación de \Stripe\AccountLink que puede ser distinta y verificando haber incluido el archivo) .

Comment: @quevedo \Stripe\AccountLink::create no me funciona, creo que eso es de una versión antigua de la API de Stripe

Comment: @SergioConejo Hay dos detalles: 1. ¿Está incluido el archivo de código de la clase? ¿lo verificaste? 2. Ese método devuelve un objeto, cuyo código debe haber sido incluido, posiblemente con algún autoload. Debes verificarlo. **Adicionalmente** puedes entrar al código de la clase y desde allí verificar el tipo de retorno e ir al código que lo ofrece para ver sus atributos y poder manejarlos. No creo que sea obsoleto o viejo, **porque parece ser el mismo que tu tratabas de usar**. Sólo que tu usabas una instancia y te sugieren hacer un llamado estático

Comment: @quevedo el otro si funciona pero este no

Comment: @SergioConejo intenta (en tu llamado antes de jsondecode) var_dump($link); y muestras que envía el volcado.

Comment: @quevedo he conseguido que funcione y he añadido la respuesta en este post: [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098275/php-variable-of-stripe-api/65098669#65098669)